# How to suppress special characters in variable expansion

Tags: powershell

```
$var = "stack`aoverflow"
$var
```

This causes a beep in the console, because

```
"`a"
```

is a [special character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters) in PowerShell.

I have a function that parses text files using `Select-String`. This causes beeps in the console any time that file contains "`a". I would like to be able to output, e.g., the `Content` property, of `Select-String` in a way that suppresses this beep.

So far I have:

```
$_.Content -Replace "`a"
```

which works, but I was wondering if there were a more elegant way to do this. The documentation describes `--%`, but I couldn't figure out how to use this for outputting a string.

Comment: See the help [about quoting rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: @stackprotector @vonpryz - I think the OP is asking how to sanitise a string so that e.g. ```write-host $str``` doesn’t make a sound for the ascii ```BEL``` character when being displayed in a console rather than how to quote the special character in code?

Comment: @mclayton This is correct. I don't have control over single and double quotes when I use SLS on a file. And obviously I can't reference a variable in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a literal (single-quoted) string:

```
PS > $Literal = '`a $Home'
PS > $Literal
`a $Home
PS >
```

Or if you need to use it in an expansion string, double-up the escape character (`):

```
PS > $Expand = "``a $Home $Literal"
PS > $Expand
`a C:\Users\keith `a $Home
PS >
```

Comment: Thanks Keith for the response. My question is regarding a solution for a variable with double quotes, e.g., the stored output of `Select-String` on a file. This cmdlet will always "double quote" the output to my knowledge. Therefore, I seek a general way to suppress this when referencing a variable that contains a "double-quoted" string. I can't expand my SLS output with single quotes, and if I'm parsing 100 files with over 100k lines collectively, I can't go into the file and add backticks at every position—or rather, I already affect the same result with my replace workaround in the OP.

Comment: I don't see any double-quoting in the output of `Select-String`. If you pipe the output to `Export-Csv`, the file will have double-quotes, but those are consumed when using `IMport-Csv`. I may not be imagining this properly, Would be great if you could edit your quesiton will more specifics and examples.

Comment: Also, are you parsing the `MatchInfo` object retrurned from `Select-String` or the `(Select-String ...).ToString()` display output???

Comment: @blaisem - note that once a string is in memory it’s neither “double quoted” nor “single quoted” - quotes are a Powershell syntax mechanism for expressing a string in *code* (and command line). similarly, cmdlets can’t return a “double quoted” string. You might find a cmdlet does “variable expansion” on an in-memory variable that contains a string, similar to how the Powershell runtime does variable expansion on double-quoted strings in source code, but once a string is in runtime memory it’s just a string and is neither double nor single quoted…

Answer (score 0):

> ...I was wondering if there were a more elegant way to do this.

*Elegant* might be quite subjective. A quite common way is to replace non-printable characters by dots, so that you actually print something for something that otherwise would not have a printed representation. You often see that in [hex dumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump) that include a corresponding ASCII character translation.

A more general approach would be to replace all non-printable characters either by dots or nothing. In ASCII, the first 32 characters are non-printable:

```
$var = "stack`aoverflow"
$var -replace '[\x00-\x1F]+', '.'
```